# Cant load youtube api in frame

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api, firefox-addon

Im tying to make a addon and just want to control youtube from the Frame property. In normal javasrcipt and html I can load the youtube api and use the player.playVideo functions but when I try to load the html page into a Frame it appreas there but I get an error:
"Type error player.playVideo is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

Iframes segregate their content from that of the page into which they are added.  If you have the youtube API in the frame, but you're calling `player.Play`from the parent page it wont work because the parent page does not have direct access to the iframe's content (ie. the API). Instead you need to call the api method from the context of the frame such as `FrameName.player.Play`

Comment: In the HTML I have my input button and in the same document I have a JS which document.getElementById("play") which calls to player.playVideo function. If I open that HTML file in the browser alone it will work clicking the custom buttons. however if I run it from the sdk and the HTML is injected into the Frame defined in the Main.js file i get this response "type error".  I might even not do it the right way, but im just playing around with the sdk.

Comment: @user3529814 the work of eternalStud is probably firefox-addon related so lots of the regular securities dont apply

Comment: You should move the button event handler wireup code into the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function.  I think the problem is that it's trying to use the player definition before its loaded into the site

Comment: @Noitidart yes u are correct, it is the sdk for firefox addons. I thought I posted in a firefox addon section.

Comment: @Darkninja955 this gives the same error. It does work in normal browsermode but as a addon it wont.

Also the youtube window appears in the Frame and I click the link I get a "SecurityError: The operation  is insecure."

anyways I think I need to read the documentation more thoroughly.